# Multi Stage BPF - How to know that I am moving to another entity?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

Following is my BPF :

A->B->C->D->E

A,B,C are associated with Entity1.
D and E are associated with Entity2.

According to the article [addOnStageChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/events/onstagechange) , when I am on Stage B, getStage() returns C. But, when I am on Stage C, getStage() returns C (since, D in on other entity).

Is there a way to know when I am moving from one entity to another entity via bpf?

Comment: Have you tried calling `formContext.data.process.getSelectedStage()` and comparing the return value with `getStage()`. If they are __same__ it would indicate you are moving to a different entity. Posting as a comment because I haven't tested it, so I don't know for sure it'll work.

Comment: I tried the above method. getSelectedStage() returns the next active stage because it is moving to the next stage.